# Web.config XML Transformation with escape character

Tags: visual-studio, xslt, web.config-transform

My ASP.net application has web.config with this appSettings key.

```
<add key="XmlTag" value="Test"/>
```

And the value i want to transform has "greater than' sign i.e.

```
<add key="XmlTag" value=">~NewValue" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
```

When the value gets transformed it transforms value to

```
<add key="XmlTag" value="&gt;~NewValue"/>
```

This is the same case if i escape the "greater than' sign in the web.config.

```
<add key="XmlTag" value="&gt;~NewValue" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
```

Here is tranformation preview using SlowCheetah in Visual Studio.

**Web.config**

[image: Web.config]

**Web.Qa.config:**
[image: Web.QA.config]

**Preview of Transform:**

[image: Web.config Preview Transform]

What do i do in my transformation configuration file so that when the file gets transformed, it adds the "greater than" sign?

Comment: As a web.config file is an XML document, an escaped `>` as `&lt;` shouldn't pose any problems. Or which error exactly do you get when using the web.config in which way exactly?

Comment: @MartinHonnen i am not getting error but the value is not getting transformed even though if i skip the character. As i said in my question, either i escape character by using &gt; or don't escape character ">", after web.config transformation it always end up with "&gt;" value. I want web.config to have ">" after transformation. p.s: &lt; is for < sign :P

Comment: Related read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62288452/3016153

Comment: Have you tried using the [property function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/property-functions?view=vs-2019)?
You can escape special characters. For example: ```<Compile Include="$([MSBuild]::Escape('MyFile.cs;MyClass.cs'))" />```. Now this will be read as one file, instead of two. The semi colon is no longer being used as a separator of files, but now its part of the name instead.