# Retaining entity in xslt stylesheet output without using character-map

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon, entities

Where did we go wrong?

When I process this xml with xslt 2 on saxon he:

```
 <data>
      <grab>Grab me and print me back &quot;</grab>
 </data>
```

using this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/data/grab"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/data/grab">
        <node><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></node>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><node>Grab me and print me back "</node>
```

But I want to retain the &quot; in the outputted xml. Therefore we needed to add a character-map:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:character-map name="specialchar">
        <xsl:output-character character="&quot;" string="&amp;quot;"/>
    </xsl:character-map>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"  use-character-maps="specialchar"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/data/grab"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/data/grab">
        <node><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></node>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which retains the &quot; entity... which, imho, looks verbose and ugly,

Is this really necessary? Is there not a more elegant alternative? If not, what is the rationale behind this?

Comment: *"But I want to retain the `&quot;` in the outputted xml."* - No, you don't. You want to find the reason why not having the `&quot;` in there is a problem, and eliminate that reason.

Comment: `<node>Grab me and print me back &quot;</node>` and `<node>Grab me and print me back "</node>` represent *the exact same* XML document, differences in the serialization are insubstantial.

Comment: @Tomalak multiple processing passes is the reason, eliminating would be cumbersome (10+ yr old technichal debt), thanks for the feedback of course

Comment: @Tomalak the samples - hailing from a unit test - simplify the question... would you like us to reformulate with a different sample? ...and thanks for the sharp feedback, of course

Comment: That wasn't sharp feedback, it was a nudge. And it certainly wasn't personal - your question lacked any details about the "why", and often people ask this particular question purely for cosmetic reasons, or because they feel using a kludge is easier than fixing a broken component.

Comment: consider us nudged... within about 3 years we hope to have factored out the kludge :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Architecturally, XSLT transforms XDM trees to XDM trees, it does not transform lexical XML to lexical XML. XDM trees do not distinguish between `&quot;` and `"`, any more than they distinguish between `<a id="5"/>` and `<a   id  = '5'></a>`. The fact that arbitrary and irrelevant differences in the way you write the XML are hidden from the XSLT programmer is very much by design, and makes it much easier to write correct transformations.

Now there are certainly use cases for preserving entity references: particularly semantic entity references like `&author;` that might take different values on different occasions. But entity references aren't a particularly good solution to that requirement; XInclude is usually better. And the argument doesn't apply to character references like `&quot;`: it's really hard to see a good use case for treating `&quot;` and `"` differently, and you certainly haven't provided one.

At a practical level, Saxon couldn't preserve the `&quot;` even if it wanted to, because it doesn't know it's there: the XML parser (which converts lexical XML to XDM) doesn't notify character references to the application. Again, that's by design: the theory is that applications shouldn't know and shouldn't care. And it has the great virtue that we don't get zillions of SO questions from application developers who failed to cater for the possibility.

Comment: Dear Michael, thank you for taking the time to most thoroughly answer our question. I hope I have not made you reiterate a mute point. As to to providing a _good_ use case for using the &quot; entity here, alas I cannot... other than: we do not control the source of the XML provided to us and refactoring code further down the pipeline takes time. I guess you heard that one a million times before. Understanding the answer as you posted it, we must be grateful that XSLT does provide a means to getting it done. Thank you! ...now I will take a few minutes to redigest your answer. :)