# XSLT to put existing !ENTITY refs inside <!DOCTYPE > of XML

Tags: xml, xslt, entity, doctype

I've reviewed existing questions/answers, but none are quite the same ask, or no answer is given.
I have an existing XML document with this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE thing PUBLIC "XXX//DTD XML DTD for things//EN" "C:\work\thing.dtd" [<!ENTITY abreve "&#x103;"><!ENTITY agr "&#945;"><!ENTITY amacr "&#x101;"><!ENTITY bgr "&#946;">]>
    <thing>
    [...]
    </thing>
```

I use this XSLT to alter the document in another unrelated way, which works fine:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/asset" priority="10">
    [...]
    <output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="no" encoding="UTF-8" doctype-public="XXX//DTD XML DTD for things//EN" doctype-system="C:\work\thing.dtd"/>
    [...]
```

but the output doesn't give the ENTITY items, just this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE thing PUBLIC "XXX//DTD XML DTD for things//EN" "C:\work\thing.dtd">
    <thing>
    [...]
    </thing>
```

The solution can read the ENTITY stuff from the file if need be, but doesn't have to, as it is the same in all instances, so it could just feed the ENTITY stuff in anew.
Thanks.

Comment: Here's an explanation why you shouldn't need to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62288452/17153010. Here are some ideas how you can do it anyway: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5985615/17153010.

Comment: Saxon has some extensions like `saxon:internal-dtd-subset` as a serialization parameter https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation11/extensions/output-extras/serialization-parameters.html or like the extension instruction https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation11/extensions/instructions/doctype.html. Perhaps if you use XSLT with an XML IDE like Stylus Studio or oXygen XML editor you can use the commercial PE and/or EE edition of Saxon these include, otherwise you would need to buy a Saxon PE or EE license.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid XSLT doesn't play well with DTDs. There's no way in standard XSLT to read the DTD of the input document or write the DTD of the output document, and there's no way to prevent entity and character references in the input being expanded (and therefore lost). There are a few tricks to work around some of these limitations, but none of them are very satisfactory.